# Окно без рамок PyQt/PySide через Qt Designer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, framelesswindowhint

Создаю форму через *Qt Designer* из библиотеки *PySide*.
Сохраняю форму как **`*.ui`** файл, потом прогоняю этот файл через `pyside-uic`, дабы получить **`*.py`** файл.

Мне нужно показать пользователю окно `без тайтла и стандартных рамок винды` (хочу сделать свой интерфейс).

Сколько не гуглил, нахожу только

```
setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Соответственно, это единственно верное решение данной задачи, 
но вот куда именно ставить этот флаг в файле дизайна - не понятно, это нигде не описано. 
Простите за непонимание в данном вопросе, возможно просто нужен свежий взгляд со стороны.

Куда конкретно вставить назначение флага `Qt.FramelessWindowHint`?

Выглядит он так:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 130, 46, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Hello world", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "GoodBye", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "TextLabel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог(галочка около ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Никогда не изменяйте модуль созданный в QtDesigner !**

Вы должны воспринимать этот модуль как файл ресурсов.

Посмотрите как правильно это делается. Только замените импорт и поменяйте `QtWidgets` на `QtGui`, так как у меня `PyQt5`

```
#from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 130, 46, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Hello world", None, -1))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "GoodBye", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "TextLabel", None, -1))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)      # <---


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = Widget()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо огромное, добрый человек :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def retranslateUi(self, Form):
...
    Form.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
...
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/W2pxc7d

Не выходит..

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn `from PyQt5.QtCore import*`